# laravel jetstream request api route middleware protected api:sanctum return unauthenticated response

Tags: laravel-sanctum, laravel-8, inertiajs, laravel-jetstream

I have a problem with 'domain' => env ('SESSION_DOMAIN', null) in the session.php file. When set SESSION_DOMAIN value in .env file, for example

> SESSION_DOMAIN=mysite.test

login don't works and there seems to be a middlaware.
If not set this parameter, login work fine, therefore when I call api protected route with sanctum maiddleware ex.

```
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/myroute', function () {
        return 'hello world!';
    });
});
```

I have unauthenticated response.
If use web.php file route and insert the same function:

```
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum'])->group(function () {
     Route::get('/api/myroute', function () {
         return 'hello world!';
    });
});
```

with api prefix, its works fines.
I followed laravel 8.x sanctum documentation https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum. In laravel projects 7.* without jetstream I had no problem.
There's any suggest or explaination for this phenomenon.
Any explanation would be helpful for me! Many Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into a similar issue where I could not authenticate any API request from my frontend. Turns out the generated Kernel.php did not include the Sanctum middleware for session cookies by default - [you have to add it manually](https://laravel.com/docs/master/sanctum#spa-configuration) in your `app/Http/Kernel.php`:

```
 'api' => [
        EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class, // <- Add and import this middleware
        'throttle:api',
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
 ],
```

After doing this API requests from my frontend are working again. Maybe this resolves your issue as well.